# Horizontal space constraint not working in iPhone 6 Plus only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, constraints

So I'm porting my app to adjust for various devices (iPhone 4/4S, iPhone 5/5S, iPhone 6/6P). My app only operates in portrait mode so the constraints and such should be very easy. I have been leveraging the new Xcode 6.2 tools such as the preview tool, and inferred view controller size, so I only have one storyboard for every device. However I have set up all the necessary constraints and the app runs and looks great on all the devices, excluding the iPhone 6P. But what confuses me is that the preview for the iPhone 6P looks exactly what I want, however when I run in the simulator its not correct. Please looks at the images below to understand the problem fully.

The desired look is this: (what it looks like running on all devices except iPhone 6P)

[image]

Now what it looks like on the iPhone 6P: (as you can see the tableview is shifted  (on both sides) inward.

[image]

However as seen in the storyboard, the preview shows it correctly:

[image]

This is what the constraints look like in the storyboard:
[image]

Hopefully you can understand the problem by now and hope you can offer some help, thanks in advance, feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: It would be useful to see the constraints you have on the offending view. It is possible that you are constraining the content to the view margin and not directly to the view.

Comment: From your last screenshot, it looks like the left leading constraint is not equal to 0. Maybe that's your problem?

Comment: Is your Leading and Trailing constraints constants set to view as 0.

Comment: You have a leading space to container constraint in the last screenshot for the table view. What's that for? Try removing that.

Comment: @MrNickBarker it seems that I am constraining to the view margin, how could I constrain to the view directly as I cannot see an option for that?

Comment: @RobertSaunders I have posted an explanation as a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have confirmed in the comments the issue is that you are constraining to the view margin instead of the view directly.

To stop constraining to a margin for an existing constraint, select it and in the `Size inspector` uncheck the `Relative to margin`for the items.

[image]

When creating a new constraint by dragging with control key, holding the alt (option) key while creating constraints will toggle the margin option.

[image]

If you are creating it with the popup menu in the lower rigth just uncheck the `Constrains to margin`

[image]